# Linq to SQL - complex trigger returned errors (how return results)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, triggers

I was hoping that I solved the problem with the triggers. According to all the documentation, if I do an insert or an upgrade in C # (via pattern Reposity) trigger must return a value. This works fine for simply triggers.

If I use a more complex trigger, I get an error on the return value.

a) If return from trigger **SELECT @@identity;**

*Member of type System.Int32 which is a type of values ​​that does not allow nulls. You can not assign a value to Null.*

b) If return from trigger: **select * from dbo.Table where IDColumn = scope_identity();**

```
Operation failed AutoSync member. In order to perform after insertion members operation
AutoSynced must have a type either automatically generated identity, or a key that does
not change the database after the insertion.
```

Used: C#, .NET FW4.5, Linq to SQL, MSSQL Express 2012 (compatibility 2008)

I'll be pleased as well as directions to the problems with Triggers and link to SQL.

More complex trigger (cleaned and reduced to a minimum):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[bitrgTable] 
   ON [dbo].[Table]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;        

    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE @new...

    -- Get inserted values
    SELECT @new... FROM INSERTED  

    -- do update all unique values
    UPDATE [dbo].[Table] SET
         ...
    WHERE 
        ...;

    -- if the last result is null
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    BEGIN
        -- Do insert new values
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
            (...)
        SELECT 
             ...
        FROM INSERTED
    END

    -- somehow return the result
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
    -- select * from dbo.table where TableID = scope_identity();
    -- SELECT @@identity;   
    SELECT ??????
END
```

Best regards, Peter

Based on the answers for Ismet Alkan complement question.

```
// Reposity class
public class Reposity
{
  private DataContext myDataContext = new DataContext();

  public void Save()
  {
    myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
  }
}

// Where working with reposity (class in console app)
public class ConsoleShell
{
   // declare variable
   Reposity myReposity = new Reposity();

  // Many methods, working with treads etc,

  // here I worked with Save()
  private void ExecuteThread(....)
  {
    ...

    // go thŕow all found results
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Oid, AsnType> kvpDot1dTpFdbAddress in dictDot1dTpFdbAddress)
    {
      // create new object instance
      CustomObjectFromLinq objCustomObjectFromLinq = new CustomObjectFromLinq();

      // append values for objCustomObjectFromLinq

      if(CONDITION == TRUE)
      {
        // save item
        myReposity.Add(objCustomObjectFromLinq);
        myReposity.Save();
      }
      else
      {
        // if want ignore result, do nothing, prevent object null
        objCustomObjectFromLinq = null;
      }

      .. next codes

    } -- end foreach
  } -- end method
} -- end class
```

Comment: this is a very easy operation using ORM. Just create a new instance of the object and assign variables needed, do create/update, call db.saveChanges(). After that you can easily get the ID from the object by yourInsertedObject.ID.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback. The answer you gave me I have implemented, but I get this error. I edited the question - the code for the detail in C # program.

Comment: After "myReposity.Save();", have you tried calling objCustomObjectFromLinq.ID?

Comment: Yes, but if I debug the code, when try execute code myReposity.Save(); I jump straight into Exception and nothing code after myReposity.Save() is no executed.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to give up triggers. Triggers in MSSQL and Linq to SQL is dislike (until now I could not resolve the problem above).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the ways you mentioned. However, it requires a huge effort and you really don't need to work around this. I'm not giving an exact answer here, but the way I got it working.

You're creating a class that has a `DataContext` as an attribute. I think it's better to create a class that inherits it. I used `DbContext` in my ASP.NET MVC3 application, instead of `DataContext`, but I don't know if there's a big deal of difference. Another thing is: I don't add an element directly to the context, instead I add it to a `DBSet` in the context. Here's my context class.

```
public class YourDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<YourObject> YourObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Operating the context:

```
public class TheClassYouOperate
{
    private YourDBContext yourDBContext = new YourDBContext();

    public int SaveAndReturnID(YourObject newObject)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // or CONDITION == TRUE for your case
        {
            yourDBContext.YourObjects.Add(newObject);
            yourDBContext.SaveChanges();
            return newObject.ID;
        }
        return 0; // or null or -1, whatever the way you'll understand insertion fails
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!